# grep all binary file in a folder to show only a specific world followed by numbers

Tags: grep

I spent several hours trying to figure out what I am doing wrong. Thanks for any help in advance.
I want to grep the string `toze359485948584` from multi different binary file within a specific folder. The first part of the string stay the same but the 12 digits after the world toze could change.

When I use

```
grep -a -o -E -r 'toze' /my folder/
```

I get the output `toze`

but when I use

```
grep -a -o -E -r 'toze[0-9]' /my folder/
```

I get no output at all.

The word `toze` is the same in all other binary files within that folder but the 12 digits following it are different from file to file.

Example of file:

```
 :?5o2g0?2?76=1?7?5                                                                 clasFSCl??˹?t0?l?Ah?Ob??9??$[??Te?J? ????C?'fھ???ӽ?Agj?(m?r??q[4 '?E??'黼}v?seUC?ؑFh??0?-?:??ꅜP?~0?zMANP1?p?????cBMac60:30:d4:2d:0d:c2???ɜm0SrNm9I4l6?5?5?=?4!3L2?2?5}3
6?636?5{1(1?/?.uDX3X3JWLHG7F?????cWMac60:30:d4:2b:ef:ab?????c
                         /U/]-?5?6m+?.?-?*?*a-4;6'.?-?0x*?.?,00?faic??˵?i0toze359485948584??˹?t#0!inst00008010-001348443E100026?????d:08seid0040E3FF32F48800180401178969456532CBE6122F11BB554?????n*0(srvn :??j?^<?`m4,G????@@???180718064325Z?????d0tsid928C7F80C073CA01???ٚR? 0?NvMR1???????T0DGSTo8En?HC??G??]???Q???????s0
,?0M/540K21                                                                                   clasNvMR??˹?t0instF5?l?Ah?Ob??9??$[??Te?J? ????C?'fھ???ӽ?Agj?(m?r??q[4 '?E??'黼}v?seUC?ؑFh??0?-?:?????l?0?bbcl1?
RiMcP?SYS?Hs9v>B|B?AC?@?A?=$;U<?;?>?C?9?:E9?4X<7?:6?9?5-4?4?68?8?355L5$2
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Could you run `grep -aoE toze. /path/to/example/from/this/question | hexdump -c` and show us the output?

Comment: -bash-3.2# grep -aoE toze. /myfolder/ | hexdump -c  
nothing is displayed

but if I add -rh to grep

-bash-3.2# grep -aoErh toze. /myfolder/ | hexdump -c
0000000   t   o   z   e 004  \n   t   o   z   e 004  \n   t   o   z   e
0000010 004  \n   t   o   z   e 004  \n   t   o   z   e 004  \n   t   o
0000020   z   e 004  \n                                                
0000024
-bash-3.2#

Comment: funny things is I can when toze or the numbers are been grepped alone it return result. But seem you can't combine the string.

Comment: Thank you for providing the output of the command, however the output is a bit mangled. The spaces between the numbers are very important here. Please paste the exact output of the command into your question as a code block. Also, don't use `-r` and a whole folder. Please `grep` only a single file, preferably the file you showed us in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Because the numbers are more than one you can try something like:

```
grep -a -o -E -r 'toze[0-9].' /my folder/
```

If you are ready to loop the files and manage them one by one you can simplify the work via:

```
strings $file|grep -a -o -E  'toze[0-9].'
```